# What does MySQL "GROUP BY NULL" do?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have some legacy code I'm maintaining and there's a SQL query in there that I don't understand. I'm hoping someone here can explain the purpose of this to me. The query looks like this:

```
select * from product_performance 
where merchantid = 2151277 and clickday >= '2011-09-01' 
group by null;
```

When I run this query without the `group by null` at the end, I get 44 rows. When I run it with the `group by null`, I get 1 row -- the first row in the previous set. What is happening here, and what is the purpose of using this grouping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's grouping the entire query by a constant value, which makes it pick a row effectively at random to return. You could get the same results using `LIMIT 1`.

Note that this idiom is not standard SQL, and may cause errors if you try it in other databases. In MySQL, you can disable this behavior by specifying the [`ONLY FULL GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) SQL mode. See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) for more details.

OTOH, `LIMIT 1` is non-standard as well, but more widely supported, and the same effect may be achieved in databases compliant with SQL:2008 with the `FETCH ... ONLY` clause. See [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) for details on that.

Answer (score 0):

hehe,
let's explain in this mode:
if you have

```
select emp_id, dept_id
from employees
group by dept_id
```

you'll get one row for every departament, and one emp_id, not guaranteed who.
That means the big data is spitted in departaments.

if you shoot

```
select emp_id, dept_id
from employees
group by dept_id, emp_id
```

you'll get data splitted by depts and emps.

But if you `group by null`, this means that **you do not split anything. *You have one group.*** And mysql will give you an emp_id, and a dept, not guaranteed from what row.